# How can I apply a crop to frames before tiling with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the following to build a preview filmstrip image by grabbing every Nth frame and tiling them into a grid:

```
ffmpeg -i "$file" -frames 1 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,$N)),tile=${COLS}x${ROWS}" -y strip.jpg
```

However the input video has black bars so I'd like to crop them out before grabbing those frames using something like:

```
-filter:v "crop=1440:1080"
```

Adding that has no effect on the tiled output image.  I have also tried incorporating that filter into the -vf option to no effect.  Is there any way to accomplish this without a second pass that renders the whole video (temporarily) cropped?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply insert crop after the select filter.

```
-vf "select=not(mod(n\,$N)),crop=1440:1080,tile=${COLS}x${ROWS}"
```

Comment: Thanks - I had tried that but my mistake was apparently that I was adding ":0:0" for the offset.  For some reason if I do that the crop does not apply in this context.